# Return a value relative to every instance of a search term

Tags: excel, search, vlookup

I have a spread sheet populated with dates (Months) and revenue figures. The sheet is structured with numerous tables all containing these month-revenue pairings but they are not all in the same columns.

I need to be able to search the whole range of cells for a given month and then each time the month is found I need to look across for the revenue figure (5 cells to the right) and return the answer.

The answer returned needs to give the total figure for all instances of the search term.

VLookup won't work because there are multiple tables and they are not all lined up.

Any advice would be very gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a VBA script for that, IMHO this is not possible to do in a formula. Here is a rough outline what you need to do:

1. Define an array of the month names as they appear in you sheet
2. Iterate this array and for each month name find all cells containing it ([this might help](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx))
3. Iterate all cells of each month and do your calculation based on this cell (find a cell with a certain offset or whatever)

If you cen provide a more specific description of your problem (preferably with example data/images), maybe we can give you a more specific answer.